# ¿Cómo eliminar la leyenda de uno de los ejes en una gráfica?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estaba intentando hacer un gráfico como este de **Excel** en **R**.

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El script que utilicé es el siguiente:

```
ggplot(hj, aes(x = Escenarios, y = value, fill=variable)) + 
+     geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
+     coord_flip()
```

Sin embargo, no logro que se quite la palabra value del eje de las x

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Las etiquetas de los ejes puedes configurarlas mediante [`theme()`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html). Particularmente, puedes configurar `axis.title.x` indicandole que va a ser un `element_blank()`:

```
ggplot(hj, aes(x = Escenarios, y = value, fill=variable)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
     coord_flip() +
     theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!!